# What are the alternatives for accomplishing this same task?

Tags: haskell

I have a structure that is instantiated in a parent function and I want to modify that instantiated data with calls to functions from that parent function. Here's a contrived example:

```
import Data.List

data MyLists = MyLists {
    myInts :: [Int],
    myBools :: [Bool]
} deriving (Show)

addIntToList :: Int -> MyLists -> MyLists
addIntToList x main_lists =
    main_lists { myInts = Data.List.insert x my_ints }
    -- might make a call to another child function that modifies main_list here, and so on (i.e., this is the vertical problem I see with this structuring)
        where
            my_ints = myInts main_lists

main :: IO()
main = do
    let my_main_lists = MyLists [1,2,3] [False, True, False]
    let my_new_main_lists = addIntToList 4 my_main_lists
    print my_new_main_lists
    let my_new_new_main_lists = addBoolToList True my_new_main_lists
    print my_new_new_main_lists
    -- and so on (this is the lateral problem I see with this code structuring)
```

What are the alternatives ways to structure this code or accomplish tasks similar to this? Is there a more concise way?

I should add that this gets particularly smelly (ie. code smell) once you're making a long chain of function calls to child functions; they all end up needing to return a new `MyLists` or just returning `main_list` without having done anything to it. That, and the parents might also have to deal with `MyList` and another return value (e.g., `-> (Bool, MyList)`).

So, you can imagine a tree structure of function calls all requiring a MyList parameter and return value; that doesn't seem optimal.

Here's a more concrete example of the kind of thing I'm talking about. Browse the code at https://github.com/mokehehe/monao (a super mario clone in haskell). You'll see that state.monad is never used, and that there are upper level structures that must flow throughout the code (e.g., GameGame in Main.hs).

Comment: what output do you expect? has the int list to be sorted?

Comment: The output is as expected (`MyLists {myInts = [1,2,3,4], myBools = [False,True,False]}`). I'm looking for a better way to structure this code.

Comment: In `addBoolToList True my_main_lists`, shouldn't that be `my_new_main_lists` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it a little more concise by using the [RecordWildCards](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards) extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
import Data.List (insert)

addIntToList :: Int -> MyLists -> MyLists
addIntToList x ml@MyLists{..} = ml{ myInts = insert x myInts }
```

The `MyLists{..}` pattern dumps the properties of the `MyLists` record into scope.  Thus, we can easily reference the old `myInts` when initializing the new `myInts`.

Conversely, if you use `..` in expression context, it will fill in uninitialized properties with corresponding names in scope.  The `addIntToList` function can also be written as:

```
addIntToList x MyLists{..} = MyLists{ myInts = insert x myInts, .. }
```

One more cool thing you can do with record wildcards:

```
someAction = do
    myInts  <- getInts :: IO [Int]
    myBools <- getBools :: IO [Bool]
    return MyLists{..}
```

Also, `Data.List.insert` is a bit verbose.  You can just say `insert`, since this import:

```
import Data.List
```

will import all of the names from `Data.List` into the namespace.  If you don't like this (e.g. because you want to define a function in your own module called `insert`), you can import it qualified:

```
import qualified Data.List as List

… List.insert …
```

As far as using `MyLists` in a program, the `StateT` monad transformer is quite helpful:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
import Control.Monad.State

...

printList :: StateT MyLists IO ()
printList = liftIO . print =<< get

program :: StateT MyLists IO ()
program = do
    printList
    modify $ addIntToList 4
    printList
    modify $ addBoolToList True
    printList

main :: IO()
main = evalStateT program $ MyLists [1,2,3] [False, True, False]
```

Comment: That extension does make it much easier to work with records, but is there a better way of structuring the code? And, I realize it's verbose to use Data.List.x, but in reading and learning from a lot of other people's source code, I've found that haskellers should be more verbose. That, or someone needs to come up with better semantic highlighting, or hoverable tooltips indicating where a function is from.

Comment: @user175492: *"That extension does make it much easier to work with records, but is there a better way of structuring the code?"*  Are you talking about the code that uses `MyLists`, or the accessors themselves?

Comment: @user175492: *"And, I realize it's verbose to use Data.List.x, but ..."*  Fair enough.  I recommend `import qualified Data.List`, since without the `qualified`, it will dump all of the names from `Data.List` into the namespace.

Comment: Okay, here's a more concrete example of the kind of thing I'm talking about. Browse the code at `https://github.com/mokehehe/monao` (a super mario clone in haskell). You'll see that state.monad is never used, and that there are upper level structures that must flow throughout the code (e.g., GameGame in Main.hs). You'll also see that the code isn't exactly pretty because of how it has to deal with the problems this creates. Is there a better way of structuring haskell code in these situations?

Comment: I think your last edit fixes the lateral structuring problem, and I guess I'd use the state transformer for child functions to fix the vertical problems.

Comment: @user175492: I see where you're coming from.  You have to marshal a lot of context through your program, so you end up with a big messy program that is hard to extend.  I don't know the answer to this, but from my experience, using monad transformers like `StateT` and `ReaderT` definitely helps.  Doing so lets you create "subroutines", meaning you can break a large context-heavy function into a bunch of simple functions that all live in the same monad.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at `Data.Lens` with a `MonadState`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Lens
import Data.Lens.Template
import qualified Data.List

data MyLists = MyLists { _myInts :: [Int]
                       , _myBools :: [Bool]
                       } deriving ( Show )

$(makeLens ''MyLists)

addIntToList :: MonadState MyLists m => Int -> m [Int]
addIntToList i = myInts %= Data.List.insert i

addBoolToList :: MonadState MyLists m => Bool -> m [Bool]
addBoolToList b = myBools %= Data.List.insert b

program :: MonadState MyLists m => m ()
program = do
    addIntToList 1
    addBoolToList False
    addIntToList 2
    addBoolToList True
    return ()

main = do
  let ml = execState program MyLists { _myInts = []
                                     , _myBools = []
                                     }
  print ml
```

**Edit:**

That's what I get for typing in untested code.  I changed the example so it actually works!  You need to have the `data-lens`, `data-lens-fd`, and `data-lens-template` modules installed (use `cabal install`).

Comment: I'd like to play around with this but it doesn't compile. I added the problems I was having with it in an edit but it needs peer review.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro but this is how I would try to achieve this

```
import Data.List (insert)

data MyLists = MyLists { myInts  :: [Int],
                         myBools :: [Bool]
                       } deriving (Show)

addIntToList :: Int -> MyLists -> MyLists
addIntToList i (MyLists is bs) = MyLists (insert i is) bs
-- if you don't care about order just do (i:is), which is faster
-- usually lists of i are denoted is (or sometimes I use ii) as a kind of plural

main :: IO()
main = do
    let myMainList = MyLists [1,2,3] [False, True, False]
    -- you would rather use CamelCase in Haskell than _
    print $ addIntToList 4 myMainList
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for; I'm interested in the structuring problem. I edited my original post to make it clearer.